# Need Help finding error in my endpoint code

Tags: plutus, smart-contract, plutus-pioneer-program, error

I cant seem to figure out whats going on? Ive been trying to create a transaction which sends ADA to a specified wallet address and can't seem to get it to work.

```
type Schema =
        Endpoint "storeFront" PaymentPubKeyHash

payPubHash :: PaymentPubKeyHash
payPubHash = "3f7846896a48c59359746ff096d63606ceb82e65900d20a9fd2b8a93"

storeFront :: AsContractError e => Promise () Schema e ()
storeFront = endpoint @"storeFront" $ \(payPubHash) -> do
    unspentOutputs <-  utxosAt contractAddress
    
    let 
        tx       = Constraints.mustPayToPubKey payPubHash (singleton adaSymbol adaToken 30000000) 
    void $ submitTxConstraintsSpending storeContract unspentOutputs tx
        
contract :: AsContractError e => Contract () Schema e ()
contract = storeFront

endpoints :: AsContractError e => Contract () Schema e ()
endpoints = contract

mkSchemaDefinitions ''Schema

$(mkKnownCurrencies [])
```

here's the error

```
Compilation Error, Line 93, Column 12 (jump)

 error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Contract () Schema e ()’
                  with actual type ‘Promise () Schema e0 ()’
    • In the expression: storeFront
      In an equation for ‘contract’: contract = storeFront
    • Relevant bindings include
        contract :: Contract () Schema e ()
          (bound at /tmp/web-ghc-work-c17f548fe0e3f9c3/Main.hs:93:1)
   |
93 | contract = storeFront
   |            ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 2):

It appears you are trying to assign a type of `Promise` to a type of `Contract`

```
contract :: AsContractError e => Contract () Schema e ()
contract = storeFront
```

Why not try this, instead:

```
contract :: AsContractError e => Contract () Schema e ()
contract = awaitPromise storeFront
```